# PostCSSS - [object Object]:[object Object]: Could not resolve the variable "$widthStandard" within "$widthStandard:"

Tags: css, postcss

```
$containerDefaultWidth: 90%;
$containerMaxWidth: 1200px;

// this code
$widthStandard: {
    width: $containerDefaultWidth;
    max-width: $containerMaxWidth;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### How can I write the $widthStandard object in PostCSS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are you confusing postcss with scss?

Your declaration above will fail!

A variable in SCSS can only contain a value, not a collection of other properties and values, let alone other variables.

See definition of what a 'property' and 'value' is:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

**So this is wrong:**

```
$widthStandard: {
    width: $containerDefaultWidth;
}
```

#### In scss you can use a %placeholderSelector or @mixin for multiple properties.

- @mixin: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin
- %placeholderSelector: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

```css
$containerDefaultWidth: 90%;
$containerMaxWidth: 1200px;

/* @mixin for reuse*/
@mixin widthStandard: {
    width: $containerDefaultWidth;
    max-width: $containerMaxWidth;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* %placeholderSelector to be extended*/
%widthStandard: {
  width: $containerDefaultWidth;
  max-width: $containerMaxWidth;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I am not using sass. using PostCSS... not helped for me but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SazzadHossainNibir Nevertheless, PostCss does not process variables. Sass does. Postcss is more like enhancement on existing pre-propressors like sass ,less or other.